# SSD showing only 195GB out of 512GB in a new laptop

Tags: partitioning, ssd

I ordered an Asus Vivobook online and received it yesterday.

On starting the laptop it shows the SSD as having only 195GB. I tried disk management where it shows Disk 0 as having 476.92GB in the lower panel but in the upper panel in Volume it shows OS(C) as having only 195.31GB.

I have searched and entered resize volume where it shows the SSD size as 475GB but shows 330GB as used (?). I tried to resize the volume but get a message - we couldn't change the volume size.

> Error code: 0x80070057.

Is this because of a bad SSD?

Please help

Comment: Where did you buy this Asus Vivobook from? Was it sold to you as new or refurbished? Might be best to contact the seller and return it for a full refund and buy it from some place else. If you don’t want to do that, this might be a case where the SSD was cloned from a 200GB  SSD volume onto a 500GB SSD drive which would not take advantage of the full 500GB and just clone a 200GB volume. You _might_ be able to fix this on your own. But again, I think it might be best to return the Asus Vivobook to the seller for a full refund.

Comment: What exactly shows Disk Management? The "lower part" as you say show the full drive whereas "C:" is a partition that may or may not occupy the whole drive.